# How to make a url in YII to verify yahoo developler

Tags: google-app-engine, yii, yahoo-api

I have a website in Yii lets say www.abc.com  now problem is yahoo wants to verify this website only on root level that is I have to make one url like this

www.abc.com/agg344zdtyttz2356-yahoo-1.html  now how can I do that, please help me. I tried putting one agg344zdtyttz2356-yahoo-1.html page but it shows this url doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

in your `app.yaml` file under handlers section you should have something like this:

```
handlers:
# yahoo verification
- url: /(agg344zdtyttz2356-yahoo-1\.html)
  static_files: yahoo/\1
  upload: yahoo/(agg344zdtyttz2356-yahoo-1\.html)
```

then put your file `agg344zdtyttz2356-yahoo-1.html` to the `yahoo` directory on your server.